# Invert string's lexicographic order value

Tags: javascript, string, sorting, lexicographic

Given that there is a lexicographically-sorted list of UTF-8 string `s1`, `s2`, `s3`, ... of unknown length, is it possible to invert each string value, such that when the list is sorted lexicographically again using the inverted value, the reverse order is now produced?

```js
function invert(s) {
    // TODO: what's here?
    return s;
}

const sample = ['', ' ', 'a', 'A', '@', '한','자', '한자', '자한'];

const original = [...sample].sort((a, b) => {
    return a.localeCompare(b);
});

const inverted = [...sample].sort((a, b) => {
    return invert(a).localeCompare(invert(b));
});

// Both should print the same.
console.log('original', original);
console.log('inverted.reverse', inverted.reverse());
```

Comment: Did you really mean to use `localeCompare` (and if yes, which locale are you using?), or did you mean to compare the string by individual charcodes (or codepoints)?

Comment: @Bergi I guess I mean to compare the string by individual charcodes--didn't think this through properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I mean to compare the string by individual charcodes

Then you'll need to use a normal comparison instead of `.localeCompare`. But yes, it's possible then to invert the string by inverting every individual charcode. This won't result in readable strings and not in valid UTF-8 either, but can be used for the comparison.

```js
function invert(s) {
    return String.fromCharCode(...s.split('').map(c =>
        0xFFFF - c.charCodeAt(0)
    ), 0xFFFF);
}

const sample = ['', ' ', 'a', 'A', '@', '한','자', '한자', '자한'];
console.log(sample.map(invert));

const original = [...sample].sort((a, b) => {
    return +(a>b)-(a<b);
});

const inverted = [...sample].sort((a, b) => {
    return +(invert(a)>invert(b))-(invert(a)<invert(b));
});

// Both should print the same.
console.log('original', original);
console.log('inverted.reverse', inverted.reverse());
```

To avoid shorter strings still being sorted first, we append `\uFFFF`. In theory this would have to be an infinite string - see [An analogue for (-/+)Infinity for characters in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75883404/1048572). For simplicity, I just assume that no strings end in `\u0000` :-)

To do it properly, you could double the size of each string so that there is enough coding space to construct an "end of string" mark that is larger than any "normal" character:

```js
function invert(s) {
    return s.split('').map(c =>
        ' ' + String.fromCharCode(0xFFFF - c.charCodeAt(0))
    ).join('') + '$';
}

const sample = ['', '\u0000', '\u0000\u0000', '.', '.\u0000', '.\uFFFF', 'a', 'A', '@', '한','자', '한자', '자한'];
console.log(sample.map(invert));

const original = [...sample].sort((a, b) => {
    return +(a>b)-(a<b);
});

const inverted = [...sample].sort((a, b) => {
    return +(invert(a)>invert(b))-(invert(a)<invert(b));
});

// Both should print the same.
console.log('original', original);
console.log('inverted.reverse', inverted.reverse());
```

Comment: Is an "infinite string" required to support `\u0000`? Would it work if the strings are first encoded to a smaller charset (e.g. `a` becomes `00072` and `\u0000` becomes `00000`)?

Comment: @Code I tried to find a way where still every character is mapped to one other character, just with some clever subtraction of numerical values, but couldn't come up with a solution. I found a way to do it using longer strings, though